# How do I set an Observable property in Angular 4 or 7?

Tags: angular, typescript, service, observable

I'm trying to set a slides[] property with the data retrieved from a json file in my carousel-service. My carousel component injects the carousel-service and calls the public getSlides() function but the returned value is an empty array.

What am I doing wrong?

Herewith the code :

```
//carousel.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CarouselService } from '../../services/carousel.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-carousel',
  templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./carousel.component.css']
})
export class CarouselComponent implements OnInit {

  slides: string[];

  constructor(private carouselService: CarouselService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSlides();
  }

  getSlides(): void {
    this.carouselService.getSlides()
      .subscribe(slides => {
        console.log('show slides', slides);
        this.slides = slides
      });
  }

}
```

Carousel.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of, ObservableInput } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CarouselService {

  slides: string[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
      this.slides = data['Carousel'];
      console.log('data loaded');
    });
  }

  public addSlide(title: string) {
    this.slides.push(title);
  }

  public getSlides(): Observable<string[]> {
    return of(this.slides);
  }

  private getJSON(): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.get("./assets/carousel.json");
  }
}
```

Comment: Services are not the best place to subscribe, instead subscribe to observable in component. change your getJSON to public and instead calling this.carouselService.getSlides(), call this.carouselService.getJSON() and why again making your array as observable if you are getting observable and by the way you are making a async operation and while calling this.carouselService.getSlides() your slides array is empty

Comment: could you post your json data

Comment: @Suryan Thank you for your comment. I took your advice and refactored my code. Moved some of the logic to the Service and others to the Component. I also changed the function which I call on the frontend to be async and I then await the output. This works brilliantly. I'll update the question with the changes but you've set me on the right path, you earned the points for answering my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the Advice of Suryan in the comments section and refactored my code to use async/await functions and on the front-end, the Component was updated to include properties.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of, ObservableInput } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CarouselService {    

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }    

  async public getJSON(): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.get("./assets/carousel.json");
  }
}

//carousel.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CarouselService } from '../../services/carousel.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-carousel',
  templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./carousel.component.css']
})
export class CarouselComponent implements OnInit {

  slides: string[];

  constructor(private carouselService: CarouselService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSlides();
  }

  getSlides(): void {
    this.carouselService.getSlides()
      .subscribe(await slides => {
        console.log('show slides', slides);
        this.slides = slides
      }.bind(this));
  }

}
```

Just a note, there are better ways do an async operation. I just read the Angular.io documentation and there [async pipes](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) one can use.